# Google Calendar and Twilio as On-Call

Tags: google-calendar-api, twilio, twilio-api

So I have been using Twilio and Google Calendar for a while now.  I was wondering if anyone had a way to connect the two together so I can create an "on-call app" that will automatically take my Twilio number and redirect that number to whoever is on call, based on Google Calendar. I see examples of sending SMS reminders of upcoming events from a google calendar, but nothing that is helping me use Google Calendar and Twilio as a way to help reduce our errors on switching the on-call number.

Comment: How are you switching the on-call number now? In other words, what powers the redirect code now? What is your back-end?

Comment: At the moment everything is done manually.  We schedule via Google Calendar then we log into the backend of Google Voice and switch the user.  We are trying to get away from Google Voice for it only allows X amount of numbers and we are growing in staff and our rotation schedule is becoming more complex and want to ensure the right person is getting the call.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure about your exact use case, but my colleague Marcos wrote about how you might [connect Google Calendar with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/building-your-own-personal-assistant-with-twilio-and-google-calendar.html). You could use that as a basis for building something that would work for you.

What I guess you would need to do is connect to Google Calendar. Then, when you have a call, look up the current person who is on call (presumably this is represented by events within the calendar). If you record the person's phone number within the event then you can extract that and use it to generate a [call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) or [SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) via Twilio.

Does this help at all?

Comment: It does -- and I was looking at the article previously.  I haven't had a chance to replicate that setup.  I more or less couldn't figure out the logic in trying to pull from the calendar in a timely fashion as the call is in progress.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you update your question with what you've done so far, I might be able to help if I know what point you've got to.

Comment: @philnash Unfortunately pictures are missing from the link you gave. If you are still working with Marcos, could you ask him to check that? :) Also I wondered whether this can be done with just Twilio infrastructure, without hosting code on your machine. Twilio has functions, is it possible to do this with them? I'm interested in doing this another way around - to check calendar during a call, and make an appointment

Comment: I'm afraid neither myself nor Marcos still work at Twilio. This blog post does pre-date Twilio Functions, but the whole thing could not be done with Functions as there is a schedule component which Twilio doesn't currently support. You could certainly use a Twilio Function to check a calendar during a call though as that can be done within a request.